# CJuiDatePicker validation messages isn't working

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, validation, yii

#### Hi.

I have a problem with form-validation in Yii framework.

Here is my **VIEW** code:

```
    <?php
$form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
  'id' => 'search-form',
  'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
  'enableClientValidation' => true,
  'focus' => array($model, 'ccc'),
  'clientOptions' => array(
    'validateOnSubmit' => true,
  ),
    ));
?>

<?php
echo $form->errorSummary($model);
?>

<div class="row">
  <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'input'); ?>
  <?php echo $form->textField($model, 'input', array('class' => 'input-medium', 'maxlength' => 11,)); ?>
  <?php echo $form->error($model, 'input'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'date'); ?>
  <?php
  $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
    'attribute' => 'date',
    'name' => 'date',
    'model' => $model,
    'language' => 'ru',
    'options' => array(
      'dateFormat' => 'dd/mm/y',
      'showAnim' => 'slideDown',
      'changeMonth' => true,
      'changeYear' => true,
      'showOn' => 'button',
      'constrainInput' => 'true',
    ),
    'htmlOptions' => array(
      'style' => 'height:15px; width:6em'
    ),
  ));
  ?>
  <?php echo $form->error($model, 'date'); ?>
</div>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

**Nothing** special. But validation messages working **only** for textField (Ajax requests are sending only with onChange textField).

How to enable CJuiDatePicker validation messages?

Comment: TBH I don't think those JQueryUI based widgets support client side validation. I haven't encountered it in any case. They're basically just a wrapper around the JUI javascript. You can perhaps add an "onSelect" function to the date widget's options and implement your own javascript validation?

Comment: Yes this is what i was afraid of. =(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to give the right id to your **CJuidatepicker** object, use `CHtml::getIdByName` to create the id value, try to the name of the html element there, it must be something like

```
'id' => CHtml::getIdByName(get_class($model) . '[' . $attribute . ']')
```

it would become something like this:

```
  $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
    'id' => CHtml::getIdByName(get_class($model) . '[date]'),
    'attribute' => 'date',
    'name' => 'date',
    'model' => $model,
    'language' => 'ru',
    'options' => array(
       'dateFormat' => 'dd/mm/y',
       'showAnim' => 'slideDown',
       'changeMonth' => true,
       'changeYear' => true,
       'showOn' => 'button',
       'constrainInput' => 'true',
    ),
    'htmlOptions' => array(
      'style' => 'height:15px; width:6em'
    ),
  ));
```

Answer (score 1):

wonde's answer "you should include a value" didn't work for me...

This is what worked:

[Yii CActiveForm date validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391130/yii-cactiveform-date-validation)

views/site/login.php originally had:

```
$form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
'id'=>'login-form',
'enableClientValidation'=>true,
'clientOptions'=>array(
    'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
),
```

Things worked when this was changed to:

```
$form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
'id'=>'login-form',
'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
'clientOptions' => array(
        'validateOnSubmit' => true,
        'validateOnChange' => true,
),
```

See:
http://sky-walker.net/temp/test/yii/testdate/index.php?r=site/login

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did and it works, i think you should include a **`value`**

```
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'reportDate'); ?>
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', 
    array( 'model'=>$model,
    'attribute'=>'reportDate',
    **'value'=>$model->reportDate,**
     'options'=>array(
     'showButtonPanel'=>true,
     'changeYear'=>true,
     'changeMonth'=>true,
      'autoSize'=>true,
     'dateFormat'=>'yy-mm-dd',
     'defaultDate'=>$model->reportDate,
     ),
    ));
    ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model,'reportDate'); ?>
```

Comment: This answer wasn't helpful but I awarded it the bounty anyway because I couldn't award the bounty to my own answer...

Answer (score 0):

this problem can be shoved simply by adding  `$form->error($model,'end_date')` after **CJuiDatePicker**.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
    'id' => CHtml::getIdByName(get_class($model) . '[date]'),
    'attribute' => 'date',
    'name' => 'date',
    'model' => $model,
    'language' => 'ru',
    'options' => array(
       'dateFormat' => 'dd/mm/y',
       'showAnim' => 'slideDown',
       'changeMonth' => true,
       'changeYear' => true,
       'showOn' => 'button',
       'constrainInput' => 'true',
    ),
    'htmlOptions' => array(
      'style' => 'height:15px; width:6em'
    ),
  ));
 echo $form->error($model,'dateTo');// added to enaple clint validation
```